# Trying to access returned JSONP data via jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have returned JSONP data that is displaying in the console formatted properly.

```
group({
  "blah": "blah",
  "blahblah": "blahblah",
  "blahblahblah": "blahblahblah"
});
```

This is my ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'test.php',
  dataType: 'jsonp', 
  cache: false,
  jsonpCallback: 'group',
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  },
  success: function(group){
    console.log(group);
    $('#theTest').append(group.name);
  },
  error: function(response1, response2, response3){
    console.log("Fail!");
    console.log(response1);
    console.log(response2);
    console.log(response3);
  }
});
```

The JSON is wrapped with 'group'. When I try and access that data though, I am unable to do so.

- group.name which has a value in the console doesn't show up when I place it on the site.
- group[0] returns g
- group[1] returns r
- group[2] returns o

I'm confused as to why everything it's being returned this way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you setting `jsonpCallback: 'group'`?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure. I had set callback: 'group' inside data earlier but moved it. My PHP file is looking for a callback.

Comment: You don't need to manually set the callback or its name.  When you do `dataType: 'jsonp'`, jQuery adds a `GET` parameter to your URL with the name of a callback it generated: `$_GET['callback']`.  You should use that when your PHP script returns: `echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($data).')';`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax request is incorrect, it should be something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'test.php',
  dataType: 'jsonp', 
  cache: false,
  jsonpCallback: 'group',
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  },
  success: function(group){
    console.log(group);
    $('#theTest').append(group.name);
  },
});
```

`dataType`, `cache` and `callback` are not to be passed as data fields and datatype should be `jsonp`

Comment: After making this change, I'm getting an error when this runs. Specifically, I'm getting: parsererror and SyntaxError {}

Comment: response2 and response3

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your server side response.  The way JSONP works is, you specify a known callback parameter that will get passed to the GET request.  On the server side, you need to extract that parameter to get the encapsulating method call for your JSON padding.

On your example with jsonpCallback: 'group', your server side needs to:

```
    $methodName = $_GET['group']
    $response = $methodName . '(' . <YOUR JSON RESPONSE> . ');'
    echo $response
```